# I have two Clash Royal accounts on one game center account

Tags: ios, clash-royale

I have two Clash Royal accounts on my only Game Center account.

(Old: iPad mini; Newest: iPhone 5s)

I want to use my newest one and delete the old one, but every time I delete the old one (on my iPad) and go back to my phone, it still asks me if I want to load my old account yet I want my newest account on both iPad and iPhone. I don't know how else to explain it.

I've deleted the entire app on my iPad mini but it continues to ask me on my phone if I want to have my old account on it. It's still in my game center.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: congratulations !!  now you cannot delete it

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the app data from iCloud:

> Go to **Settings > General > Usage**
>
> There will be a section called **iCloud** with a **Manage Storage**
>   option. Tapping this will load all your data stored on iCloud.
>
> Under the **Documents & Data section**, check to see if your game has
>   data saved to iCloud. If it does, simply tap on it and tap on the edit
>   button in the top right hand corner to bring up the Delete prompt.

[Source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94101)